What wind speeds would be required for a 10-ft section of W12x336 A36 I-beam to puncture a spent nuclear fuel cask?
You can assume it's a "normal" hit with the I going directly into the outer surface of the cask. The beam itself is 336lb/ft, so 3360lb in total. The cross sectional area for this particular I beam is 98.8in^2
I know there's been extensive testing of these casks on trains and rocket sleds, but the maximum speed they tested was under half the maximum speed of a Cat 5 hurricane.
If you have a particular cask whose design you're familiar with, its okay to scope the answer to just that cask.

According to the document, Safety of Spent Fuel Storage, dry cask storage devices are designed to "Resist earthquakes, tornadoes, floods, temperature extremes, and other scenarios".

"... on trains and rocket sleds, but the maximum speed they tested ..." It's not the speed of the train that will cause damage - it's the deceleration and stress of impact. There will be little correlation between crash testing and static wind loading.

Its not the wind I'm concerned with, it's what's in it! Girders, trees, etc

So calculate the energy held in a girder thrown by a hurricane hitting the container - then evaluate "how" it hits ie direct, perpendicular, angled etc etc

the answer to your question cannot be a no

I think your question is too broad. First part is which potentially dangerous object can be propelled by hurricane wind and the second part is about the impact on the cask. And since you aske with "could", I would agree with @jsotola that the answer cannot be no.

I have modified the question to be specific to a standard size I-beam

How realistic would it be for such a hefty I beam to be near a spent nuclear fuel cask for it to pose a risk in a Cat 5 Hurricane or similar event?

Have you seen the debris fields that a Cat 5 produces? There are at least 10 active US commercial plants in areas that have seen a major hurricane in the last decade. These winds regularly carry much heavier trees/cars etc. I believe it's a reasonable inquiry.
